# CPropertyPage derived dialog doesn't close on Esc when showing as a standalone dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog which I need to show both inside a CPropertySheet and as a standalone dialog. I've chosen not to have 2 separate classes to avoid code redundancy (I make changes a lot in those dialogs, and having to sync 2 classes constantly would be hell), instead when I want to show it as a standalone dialog, I just call CPropertyPage::DoModal. This causes some problems, but I've fixed most of them.

However, some still remain, namely enter and esc don't work. Also pressing tab doesn't change the focus. This makes me think that CPropertyPage eats up all keyboard input, or maybe it tries to pass them to its parent.

Any ideas how I can override that behaviour in the standalone mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would work for you. I don't have a dialog that I can test this with so I am doing this all from memory but I believe you could add a bool that you set when you call `DoModal` or expose it as a property that you set before the call to `DoModal` to indicate it is running as a stand alone dialog, then override `PreTranslateMessage` like this:

```
CMyPropertyPage::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (m_runningAsStandalone && pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        UINT key = pMsg->wParam;
        switch(pMsg->wParam)
        {
            case VK_RETURN:
                 OnOK();
                 return TRUE;
            case VK_ESCAPE:
                 OnClose();
                 return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return CPropertyPage::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

You may also find this link helpful http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125645

Comment: When I looked at the source code of `CPropertyPage::PreTranslateMessage`, it turned out it was just calling `CWnd::PreTranslateMessage`. So I tried just calling `CDialog::PreTranslateMessage`, and things miraculously started working, including the tab key, and everything.